# Library for ASCII Art with choosable alphabet

Tags: ascii-art

I'd like to convert an image to ASCII art with a program or graphics library but I would like to specify which palette (of symbols) to use. So basically I want an image which is rendered as Text from some alphabet A that is a subset of the full ASCII-Table, for example A := {a,b,c,x,y,z,@,\,/} or so.

Is there a library / program for such conversions that let's you specify the palette for the text-rendering?

Cheers

Comment: http://www.figlet.org/: FIGlet is a program for making large letters out of ordinary text - unfortunately I want to convert an image so no luck there :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do ASCII art image conversion algorithms work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394882/how-do-ascii-art-image-conversion-algorithms-work)

Answer (score 3):

You want [Figlet](http://www.figlet.org/), which is fully Unicode compliant, supports a variety of typefaces, and has +1 awesome.