# rank ascii characters by intensity/darkness/lightness

Tags: plot, ascii-art

I want to quickly output contour plots of result calculated on a server. I log in with putty so the output should be text based (i know how to send graphics i prefer text).

To output the contour plots i need to know light intensity of each symbol. is there a table like that?

Comment: If you  have bitmaps for a typical rendering of ASCII characters, then it's simple to calculate.

Comment: yes, i can create a bitmap of all characters then see the average grey color and get the result. i'm just asking if there is someone who did that already. it seems like someone who works with ascii art would know of something like that. this will also save time to other people

Answer (score 1):

Use a library, like [aalib](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aalib/) or [libcaca](http://sam.zoy.org/projects/libcaca/). Don't know a table though...

EDIT:

Intensity is font specific...