# JPEG , Bitmap , PNG printed in console

Tags: c#, bitmap, png, console-application, jpeg

I want to take each pixel and to print it to the console so that i can see the picture in black and white in the console screen.

Is that even possible?

i tried to load it with the system.IO File , but it wont work.

any suggestions?

thanks.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this? The console is not a *graphical* user interface, it is a *text* user interface.

Comment: As in, printing out an image to the windows command console, that is not possible...

Comment: Is what even possible? What do you mean by "printed in console"? Do you want an image to show up in a console? Do you want it converted to ASCII-art? Do you want to display information about the image on the console?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/97542/how-do-i-make-my-terminal-display-graphical-pictures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The windows command prompt is strictly text based(essentially all command prompts/terminals are this way). So, you cannot display ***GRAPHICAL*** content in a ***TEXT*** focused interface.

The only conceivable way(as far as I can tell) is what @EricFinn inquired about. Possibly converting the image to ASCII-art and printing each line to the command line. You may be able to modify [THIS EXAMPLE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670739/Csharp-ASCII-Art-Tutorial) if you want to move in the ASCII direction.

Comment: thanks a lot guys. for those who ask why? its for a game i build.and ascii sounds terrific! bwtrent , in the link you posted its for winforms , how about doing it in the console?

Comment: i want to do something like here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1-_MiF-w3M

Comment: @God, [THIS SO QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394882/how-do-ascii-art-image-conversion-algorithms-work) should give you direction on how where to start. Each new line of ascii characters would be a new line in the console.